# Unable to connect ssh to ec2 through config file in ubuntu. Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

Unable to connect to SSH through Ubuntu. But it works fine on MAC.

My Config File

```
Host testserver
User ubuntu
IdentityFile '/home/kavin/.ssh/AnotherKey.pem' 
HostName ec2-54-201-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Connecting through SSH

```
$ ssh testserver
```

This is same i did for Mac and for my Ubuntu. It works perfectly in Mac but in Ubuntu an error is thrown `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`

Now i tried the alternate way `ssh -i '/home/kavin/.ssh/AnotherKey.pem'  ec2-user@54.201.xxx.xxx`

This works fine in both Mac and Ubuntu.

Can you please tell me where i went wrong

These are the logs of $ ssh testserver -v

```
OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/kavin/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/kavin/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for testserver
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-200-26-1.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [54.200.26.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file '/home/kavin/.ssh/AnotherKey.pem' type -1
debug1: identity file '/home/kavin/.ssh/AnotherKey.pem'-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 90:e1:d7:01:ab:cf:eb:2c:4b:8f:b2:5e:ad:05:a5:b8
debug1: Host 'ec2-54-200-26-1.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/kavin/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: '/home/kavin/.ssh/AnotherKey.pem'
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

Comment: It looks like you're using the incorrect key. Can you post the output of "ssh testserver -v"

Comment: Added the output of -v

Comment: You have to ensure that AnotherKey.pem is the keyfile that you downloaded from AWS when you created the keypair.

Comment: remove the quotes from here IdentityFile '/home/kavin/.ssh/AnotherKey.pem'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say,

```
ssh -i '/home/kavin/.ssh/AnotherKey.pem' ec2-user@54.201.xxx.xxx
```

from ubuntu m/c works and `ssh testserver` fails. I would suggest comment other lines from config file and just keep

```
IdentityFile /home/kavin/.ssh/AnotherKey.pem
```

Make sure, you remove the quotes and the path should directly be available to key.

Answer (score 1):

Goto Terminal:

1. gksu nautilus (enter your root password)
2. browse to /etc/ssh/
3. copy your 'key' in /etc/ssh/
4. open ssh_config
5. copy paste:

   Host testserver

   HostName ec2-54-201-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

   User ubuntu

   IdentityFile /etc/ssh/AnotherKey.pem
6. save - exit
7. open new terminal
8. sudo -i
9. enter password
10. cd /etc/ssh
11. chmod 400 'your-key'
12. ssh testserver

-- make sure your 22 port is open

https://askubuntu.com/questions/410218/how-to-close-an-open-port-in-ubuntu-12-04